# Why self.size give me back 100,100 in kivy

Tags: kivy

I need the size of the window but self.size give me back 100,100

This is the code:

```py
from kivy.config import Config

Config.set('graphics', 'width', '700')
Config.set('graphics', 'height', '400')

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.graphics.context_instructions import Color
from kivy.graphics.vertex_instructions import Quad
from random import randint
from kivy.uix.relativelayout import RelativeLayout
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout


class MyWidget(FloatLayout):

    enemis_list = []
    enemi_width = .1
    enemi_height = .1
    
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.init_enemis()
        self.new_enemi_cordinates()

    def on_size(self, instance, value):
        
        print(self.size)

#creo nemico        
    def init_enemis(self):
        with self.canvas:
            Color(1, 1, 1)
            self.enemis_list.append(Quad())

#posiziono nemico           
    def new_enemi_cordinates(self):

        r = randint(0, self.width)

        x1, y1 = r, self.height*0.1
        x2, y2 = r-(self.width*self.enemi_width)/2, y1+(self.height*self.enemi_height)/2
        x3, y3 = x1, y1+(self.height*self.enemi_height)
        x4, y4 = x2+(self.width*self.enemi_width), y2

        self.enemis_list[-1].points = [x1, y1, x2, y2, x3, y3, x4, y4]
        
        print(self.size)

class MyGameApp(App):
    pass
    
MyGameApp().run()
```

I try "Widget, BoxLayout, RelativeLayout" instead FloatLayout  but the result is the same

Instead the method on_size() works properly give me back 700,400

Comment: Can you please elaborate what exactly do you want ?

Comment: I need the size of the window

Answer (score 0):

Your `on_size()` method will get called twice. Once when the `MyWidget` gets the default size for all widgets assigned (which is `(100,100)`), and again later when it gets its actual size set.

Comment: print() inside on_size() is executed only one time if i don't resize the window. The result of the preview code is 100,100 and 700,400